# Not able to install from USB on a Mac

Tags: installation, boot, 13.04, usb, macosx

I did everything correctly. I ran the iso (rebooting the Mac, then booting from USB), and then chose the option to install Ubuntu. I then got a black screen for about 10 seconds, and then received the following message:

```
ata_id[350]: HDIO_GET_IDENTITY failed for '/dev/sdc': Invalid argument
```

What is going on here? I really need some serious help. What should I do? I've already partitioned my disk into LINUX and LINUX SWAP, both with the correct format (MS-DOS "FAT").

Thanks to anyone who helps.

Answer (score 0):

Before I get into answering your question, I have a few questions of mine:

- What tool did you use to extract and install Ubuntu onto your USB drive?
- What version of Ubuntu are you installing (12.04, 12.10, 13.04, etc.)?

I am only basing my answer on these opinions of mine:

- You don't use a linuxliveusb creator;
- You are trying to install Ubuntu 13.04.

So here you go:

1. Download and install any liveusb creator for Mac (preferably 'UNetbootin');
2. Run that program and make sure you have it focus on your USB drive and your .iso file. (Make sure to re-format the drive to 'FAT32' before installing!)
3. When it's finished, close out the window and reboot your Mac.
4. Press and hold the 'Option' key until the device menu pops up. Now select your USB device you installed Ubuntu on and select 'Install Ubuntu 13.04'. If this doesn't work, look for an option in the grub called 'Try Ubuntu 13.04'.

If this still doesn't work, consider changing USB devices or reformat and install Ubuntu 12.10 (or .04) on your USB drive. Sorry if I could not help you. :C